# Why any quotes are ignored in the Git config?

Tags: windows, git

git, windows 7. I try set a text editor via different ways:

> $ git config --global core.editor "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe" 
>   $ git config --global core.editor \"C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe\" 
>   $ git config --global core.editor 'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'

But when I look the config file (via the `git config --list` command), I get the same result:

> core.editor=C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe

So, I can't do a commit, I get an error:

> $ git commit C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe: **C:Program:
>   command not found error**: There was a problem with the editor
>   'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++ .exe'. Please supply the message
>   using either -m or -F option.

I tried edit the **.gitconfig** file manually (I added the quotes) but it is not help me.

Why quotes are ignored and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try that

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:\Program Files\Notepad++\notepad++.exe'"
```

Comment: @DAXaholic, What's the reason/explanation for this odd syntax?

Comment: @Pacerier In PowerShell and zsh, double-quotes expand variables whereas single quotes denote string literals. It's often why $LOCAL, $REMOTE, and $MERGED don't render when passed within double-quotes (terminal expects these to be environment variables like $PATH, but your environment doesn't have them, so it outputs blank. This question is 7 years old now, so I believe Git for Windows has been updated since to add double-quotes, but I suspect the terminal is rendering ("expanding") the string in double-quotes first and printing out the result, so the quotes aren't copied.

Comment: @A.Hendry I stubled over this error just today..

Comment: git for windows SHOULD just accept "". Lost one hour today.

Answer (score 1):

You should use forward slashes (/) rather than backslashes (\) in your pathname.

Source: [[here](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Development/SubmittingPatches/GitForWindows)] under "Configuring git and the helpers"

Comment: I tried: `git config --global core.editor "/C/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"`, but it is not help me too.

Comment: try `git config --global core.editor "C:/Program Files/Notepad++/notepad++.exe"`

Comment: no it is not work too. But DAXaholic's way works fine.